# Magento search is not working after upgrade to latest version

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, magento-upgrade, version

Does any one know how i can solve my problem ? . becuase my search is not workinig after upgrade magento version

Answer (score 0):

If search not-working in Magento 2 stores is just setting up the right configurations. For this, navigate to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search and set 1 in the Minimal Query Length line and 128 in the Maximum Query Length line.

Then enable search suggestions and set 2 in the Search Suggestions Count line. Don’t forget to save the changes and flush the cache.

Comment: I got issue in magento 1.9.4.5